# checking timeStamp in ant 1.10 later of build.xml

Tags: ant, salesforce

I'm checking two timestamp in build.xml file. I set

```
fd.Download.PackageXML.TimeStamp = '2023/10/15 12:20:20'
```

and have system `fd.Download.PackageXML.RealTimeStamp`. I checked two timestamp by using `<equals arg1='' arg2=''>`. The two timestamps are equal. But the output is not equal. How can I do that?

Comment: You have to try usin scripting language like JavaScript or Groovy within your Ant build file to compare the timestamps.